# How to access functions in a closure?

Tags: r

Given the dependencies of `checkboxGroupInput`

```
library(shiny)
codetools::findGlobals(checkboxGroupInput)
```

How could I access/print "hidden" functions such as `choicesWithNames`?

Comment: `getAnywhere("choicesWithNames")`

Comment: shiny:::choicesWithNames or since it's open source go to the guthub repo